# SOAP vs HTTP POST in WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, http-post, jaxws-maven-plugin

I have the following wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
         xmlns:ota="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
         targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
         name="OCDistributorsService">

<types>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelSearchRQ.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelSearchRS.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRQ.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRS.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelAvailRQ.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelAvailRS.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelResRQ.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="xsd/OTA_HotelResRS.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
</types>

<message name="ListPropertiesRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelSearchRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="ListPropertiesResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelSearchRS"/>
</message>

<message name="GetPropertyDetailsRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="GetPropertyDetailsResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRS"/>
</message>

<message name="GetMultiAvailabilityRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="GetMultiAvailabilityResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRS"/>
</message>

<message name="GetSingleAvailabilityRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="GetSingleAvailabilityResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRS"/>
</message>

<message name="CheckAvailabilityRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="CheckAvailabilityResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelAvailRS"/>
</message>

<message name="DoReservationRequest">
    <part name="request" element="ota:OTA_HotelResRQ"/>
</message>
<message name="DoReservationResponse">
    <part name="response" element="ota:OTA_HotelResRS"/>
</message>

<portType name="OCDistributorsV1Port">

    <operation name="ListProperties">
        <input message="ota:ListPropertiesRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:ListPropertiesResponse"/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetPropertyDetails">
        <input message="ota:GetPropertyDetailsRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:GetPropertyDetailsResponse"/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetMultiAvailability">
        <input message="ota:GetMultiAvailabilityRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:GetMultiAvailabilityResponse"/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetSingleAvailability">
        <input message="ota:GetSingleAvailabilityRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:GetSingleAvailabilityResponse"/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="CheckAvailability">
        <input message="ota:CheckAvailabilityRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:CheckAvailabilityResponse"/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="DoReservation">
        <input message="ota:DoReservationRequest"/>
        <output message="ota:DoReservationResponse"/>
    </operation>

</portType>

<binding name="OCDistributorsV1POST" type="ota:OCDistributorsV1Port">

    <http:binding verb="POST"/>

    <operation name="ListProperties">
        <http:operation location="ListProperties"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetPropertyDetails">
        <http:operation location="GetPropertyDetails"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetMultiAvailability">
        <http:operation location="GetMultiAvailability"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="GetSingleAvailability">
        <http:operation location="GetSingleAvailability"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="CheckAvailability">
        <http:operation location="CheckAvailability"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

    <operation name="DoReservation">
        <http:operation location="DoReservation"/>
        <input/>
        <output/>
    </operation>

</binding>

<service name="OCDistributorsServiceV1">
    <port name="POST" binding="ota:OCDistributorsV1POST">
        <http:address location="http://sandbox-api-distributors.odigeoconnect.com/distributors/v1/"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

And I'm using jaxws-maven-plugin to auto generate my client classes. My maven plugin conf is as follows:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sei/>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <packageName>com.odigeo.accommodation.fare.provider.odigeoconnect.generated</packageName>
                <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/conf/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/gen-java</sourceDestDir>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>com/odigeo/accommodation/fare/provider/odigeoconnect/odigeoconnect.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/conf/resources/com/odigeo/accommodation/fare/provider/odigeoconnect</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is, that when I try to call the WS, using a the generated ServiceClient that provides the port as follows:

```
final OTAHotelAvailRS response = port.getSingleAvailability(request);
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot create SOAP envelope from: {http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}OTA_HotelAvailRS
```

So, the wsdl clearly states that the request is HTTP POST, so why is my generated client trying to parse the response as SOAP? The response from the server is a valid XML.